# Unable to reference env variable when script is run as a service

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I have an environment variable `KEY`. It is defined in `.bashrc`

```
export KEY=...
```

I can confirm that the variable is set with `echo $KEY`.

I have a Python script that references the variable with:

```
os.environ.get('KEY')
```

When I run the script directly (`python3 main.py`), I able to confirm that the script is able to reference the key.

However, I am running the script as a service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Tool

[Service]
Restart=always
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/tool
ExecStart=/var/lib/tool/bin/python3 /var/lib/tool/main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When run as a service (running on Ubuntu), `os.environ.get('KEY')` returns `null`.

How can I ensure the script, when running as a service, has access to the environment variable?

Comment: `User=root` This means the service is running as the root user, not as you, so it does not have access to your environment.  You need to add the appropriate variable to the root user's environment.

Comment: The variable is already set for root.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not run for services. It might be set for _an interactive shell_ running as root, but systemd doesn't start shells at all, much less interactive ones.

Comment: Where are env variables defined for services?

Comment: And moreover, **you don't want** your services running `.bashrc` files. Interactive customization shouldn't need to be done by people who have to double-check "will this change I'm making to the environment I do administration in break any of my services?"

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is put an `Environment=var=value` in the `.service` file. Systemd allows global configuration too -- but this is a place to read the systemd documentation.

Comment: (There's a relevant Server Fault question too: [How to set environment variable in systemd service](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service))

Comment: Also see the `EnvironmentFile=` directive, which lets you specify _per service_ which files it looks in to read environment variables to set during that service's execution. Note that that files so specified are read _by systemd_, not by a shell; it can't contain arbitrary shell commands and its assignments need to confirm to systemd's quoting/escaping rules.

Comment: It's common, btw, to do something like `EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/%N.conf` so `foo.service` will read environment variables from `/etc/conf.d/foo.conf`

Comment: (aside: `.bashrc` isn't traditionally the right place to define environment variables for interactive shells either! The traditional thing is to put your environment variables in `.profile` / `.bash_profile` and your shell-local settings that _aren't_ exported to the environment in `.rc` / `.bashrc` -- that way the environment variables are only initialized in a _login_ shell and not reread every time you start a new _interactive_ shell as a child of that login shell).